# nativeStorage in ionic 2 and providers

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to store a token in local storage, and if it exists tweak it slightly and then use it on the page.

With ionic 1 it was easy to create a service that just got the data from local storage, changed it and returned it so the main component can do with it as it will.

however now that NativeStorage.getItem() returns a promise, how do i force the service to fully complete getting the item, and finishing my other changes before returning the tweaked token as the data?

I want to be able to do:

```
export class Test{
    let tok = "";
    constructor(tokenService:TokenService){
       this.tok = tokenService.getToken()
    }

    ngOnInit(){
      alert(this.tok + " Is your token");
    }
}
```

and in tokenService the provider have:

```
getToken(){
// this doesn't work now because it will return undef for modified_token not waiting for the promise to finish
    let modified_token:string; 
    NativeStorage.getItem('token').then(
        data=>{ 
            modified_token = data + 'modified'; 
        }
    ); 
    return modified_token
}
```

Do i just have to have another main function that is called when the promise is finished?

like:

```
getToken(){
    return NativeStorage.getItem('token')
}
```

and instead of in the constructor in ngOnInit have:

```
ngOnInit(){
 tokenService.getToken().then(
    data => { 
        let modified_token = data + "modified";
        mainAction(modified_token);
    })
}
```

and mainAction() has the rest of what i want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i just have to have another main function that is called when the
>   promise is finished?

That's one way to do it. You could also keep all the related logic inside the `getToken` method by returning a new Promise like this:

```
getToken(){
   return NativeStorage.getItem('token').then(data => return data + 'modified')
}
```

And then

```
ngOnInit(){
 tokenService.getToken().then(
    modifiedToken => { 
        mainAction(modifiedToken);
    })
}
```

**UPDATE:** the answer was updated according to @SamMason comment.

Comment: your `getToken()` looks unnecessarily complicated.  Why is it not just `return NativeStorage.getItem('token').then(data => data + 'modified')`?  Promises "chain" nicely!

Comment: @SamMason you're absolutely right; I've updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks a lot :)